# tcpdump filter by ESP SPI value

Tags: tcpdump

Does tcpdump support filtering by ESP traffic (proto 50) with a particular SPI value?

It displays this value, so you would think this is possible!

```
21:15:23.143805 IP 64.7.134.1 > 64.7.139.200: ESP(spi=0x0d8f42b8,seq=0x27)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible with a filter such as `"ip proto 50 and ip[((ip[0]&0x0f)<<2):4]==0x0d8f42b8"`

... which breaks down as:

- `ip proto 50`: All ESP packets.  (**Note** that with newer versions of [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) it is apparently possible to specify `ip proto esp` instead.)

**and** that also match a specific spi

- `ip[0]&0x0f`: The number of 32-bit words of the IP header
- `((ip[0]&0x0f)<<2)`: The offset to the ESP payload and spi field
- `ip[((ip[0]&0x0f)<<2):4]`: The 4 bytes comprising the spi field
- `ip[((ip[0]&0x0f)<<2):4]==0x0d8f42b8`: A spi field that matches the hexadecimal value `0x0d8f42b8`

It might be tempting to just use a simplified filter of `ip[20:4]==0x0d8f42b8`, but that assumes fixed-size IP headers with the default IP header size of 20 bytes.  I suppose if you know your IP headers are definitely 20 bytes, then it's OK to use, but I think it's much safer never to make that assumption.